# Load External Page, but use local CSS

Tags: css

title says it all!

I'm trying to load some external content (HTML / JS / etc) but style it using a local css definitions.
I know that this is impossible using an iframe. So i tried loading the external page into a div instead.

I've tried the following 2 methods:

```
<div> 
<object type="text/html" data="http://myexternalsite.com" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
</object>
</div>
```

and

```
<script>
    $("#siteloader")
        .html('<object data="http://myexternalsite.com"/>');
</script>
```

And i'm still not able to perform styling for external load elements using local css.
When I do a "Inspect Element" on the external content, it shows that none of my local css declarations are picked up by the element.

I've also tried influencing the external elements by using jquery to show / hide them. Such as:
    $("#idinexternalpage").hide();

But using jquery also does not seem to work.

Any ideas anyone?

Yes you are correct i'm trying to load external content but style it locally using either CSS / JQuery / both.

Comment: I don't know if this would work, but have you tried inserting a `link` tag inside the `object` element when you create it with jQuery? Like `<object><link href=""></object>`.

Answer (score 0):

May i recommend you use a [user style](https://userstyles.org/)? Install the Stylish extension (Firefox and Chrome), and you can then modify the style for a specific site/page.